# Can Stylus be configured to compile .css once, instead of on .styl change?

Tags: css, node.js, production-environment, stylus

In development, recompiling .css every time .styl changes is highly convenient. But on production, we don't want to spend resources compiling on every request; we'd like to compile once, on app start.

Can Stylus be configured this way?

Answer (score 0):

[SocketStream](https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream/blob/master/src/client/pack.coffee) has an asset packer than pre-compiles the css, js and template files in production mode. Perhaps use that pattern of checking for an environment variable (development or production) and then serving either an on-the-fly compiled set of files, or a pre-packed set of assets that are done when node starts for the first time (i.e. compile your css and then use the `fs` module to write them to disk).

The following is taken from the [stylus module](https://github.com/socketstream/ss-stylus/blob/master/wrapper.js) of socketstream:

```
stylus(input, {filename: path, paths: [dir.join('/')]})
  .render(function(err, css) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  cb(css);
});
```

The cb method is the callback that is used to feed a [fs.writeFileSync](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_filename_data_options) call that takes in the compiled file. So, in the end you have 4 parts:

1. Check an environment variable upon app start.
2. If dev mode, then just serve up the files as you are doing now.
3. If production mode, then pre-compile the css files and output them into a directory as a minified css file.
4. Change references in your header HTML to the minified css file(s).

Comment: Sure, I added more detail to my answer.